# Getting UI form to render inside HTML table in GAS

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sites

In Google Sites, I am trying to add a short form consisting of a text box and a submit button as a cell in a row inside an html table. One copy of the form for each row in the table. I am trying to collect input data for each table row.

HTML File:

```
<html>
  ...
  function showForm(){ // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/gui_builder#including
    var app=UiApp.createApplication();
    app.add(app.loadComponent("myGui"));
    return app;
  }
  ...
  <table><tr><td><?=showForm()?></td></tr></table>
  ...
</html>
```

I then call the .html file from my doGet() function in my .gs file using HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile() method.

The table renders properly, except where I expect the form to appear, I instead get the text/string "UiApplication" instead of the text box + submit button combo.

Am I on the right track? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the wrong track.

You can't mix & match components from **HtmlService** and **UiApp**. GUI Builder is a packaged **UiApp** component.

Just stick with a FlexTable and fill the table cells with your builder component. But don't forget to set a prefix:

```
var flextab = app.createFlexTable();
for (row=0; ...)
  for (col=0; ...)
    flextab.setWidget(row, col, app.loadComponent("myGui", {"prefix": "row"+row+"col"+col});
```

BTW - you can only have one **UiInstance** in your web app. Call `UiApp.createApplication()` only once. If you need the **UiInstance** later on, you can always find it with `UiApp.getActiveApplication()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The createFlexTable() is definitely a helpful point in the right direction! =]